# I'm trying to write a player object that performs the simple task of moving on the canvas with WASD but doesn't move

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Even tho everything seems fine at first glace, when I actually press on WASD it doesn't move. I'm trying to figure out if I should pass down "e" as some argument into the object or to call it somehow, but I'm not sure what's going wrong. Also I know this is a terrible way to implement WASD movement, I promise I will look into doing it better, but first I Want to manage to implement an object out of it before I branch out.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const image = document.getElementById('player');

function Player() {
  this.location = {w: 200, h: 200, x: 20, y: 200, speed: 5, dx: 0, dy: 0};

  this.drawPlayer = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, this.location.x, this.location.y, this.location.w, this.location.h);
  }

  this.clear = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  this.newPos = function() {
    this.location.x += this.location.dx;
    this.location.y += this.location.dy; 

    this.detectWalls();
  }

  this.detectWalls = function() {
    if(this.location.x < 0) {
      this.location.x = 0;
    }

    if(this.location.x + this.location.w > canvas.width) {
      this.location.x = canvas.width - this.location.w;
    }

    if(this.location.y < 0) {
      this.location.y = 0;
    }

    if(this.location.y + this.location.h > canvas.height) {
      this.location.y = canvas.height - this.location.h;
    }
  }

  this.moveUp = function() {
    this.location.dy = -this.location.speed;
    }

    this.moveDown = function() {
    this.location.dy = this.location.speed;
    }

    this.moveRight = function() {
    this.location.dx = this.location.speed;
    }

    this.moveLeft = function() {
    this.location.dx = -this.location.speed;
    }

    this.keyDown = function(e) {
      if (e.key === 'd') {
        this.moveRight();
      } else if (e.key === 'a') {
        this.moveLeft();
      } else if (e.key === 'w') {
        this.moveUp();
      } else if (e.key === 's') {
        this.moveDown();
      }
    }

    this.keyUp = function(e) {
      if (
        e.key == 'd' ||
        e.key == 'a' ||
        e.key == 'w' ||
        e.key == 's'
      ) {
        this.location.dx = 0;
        this.location.dx = 0;
      }
    }
}

let player = new Player();

function update() {
  player.clear();
  player.drawPlayer();
  player.newPos();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);
```

Comment: Never update the position inside the `requestAnimationFrame` callback! This will make the game faster in certain devices and slower in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here start from something that actually moves the Player, then complicate it as much as you like

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png"
image.onload = update;

function Player() {
  this.location = { w: 80, h: 100, x: 50, y: 10, speed: 5 };

  this.drawPlayer = function() {    
    ctx.drawImage(image, this.location.x, this.location.y, this.location.w, this.location.h);
  }

  this.clear = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }  
}

let player = new Player();
function update() {
  player.clear();
  player.drawPlayer();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);     
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'd') {
      player.location.x += player.location.speed;
    } else if (e.key === 'a') {
      player.location.x += -player.location.speed;
    }    
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

As you can see I removed a lot of your code just to focus on the problem of moving the player with the keys, you should do the same when asking a question, just keep your code example very small, that way is easier for others to start troubleshooting.

Comment: I appreciate your edit but, I have a version of the code that does exactly that exactly like you did it... The problem is how do I put that last function you made (aka the document.addEventListener) INSIDE of the object Player?

Also thank you for the feedback, next time when I post something I will try to simplify more, it's my first time actually writing a question on Stack overflow

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that ... I would not put that in the object player, same with clearRect that should not be on the player but global to the entire game, I'm sure as your game gets more complicated the keydown could be for other objects as well

Comment: I managed to do it by rewriting the last two lines as follows:
document.addEventListener('keydown', player.keyDown.bind(player));
document.addEventListener('keyup', player.keyUp.bind(player));

Thanks for the help tho!